# Mesh is Transparent

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, mesh, shaders, transparency

Just playing around with some models and I'm trying to make this look like a crystal but its transparent and its not supposed to be. Someone mind telling me what's up with it?
[image]

Comment: maybe change the alpha value in the shader???

Comment: That worked a charm can you explain what the alpha property does though? Because I didn't think it changed transparency just emission strength (I don't know how to use nodes so I'm watching tutorials and just kind of guessing at what stuff does)

Comment: Well.. alpha drives transparency: 1 is not transparent, 0 is full transparent... no more

Comment: It is easier to think Alpha in terms of occlusion: 1 fully occluded, 0 no occlusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@lemon answered perfectly it was the alpha value.